# Hazelcast: Node IP gets added to blacklist automatically

Tags: hazelcast, apache-karaf

We ran into an issue when using Hazelcast indirectly through Apache Karaf Cellar. Sometimes the two nodes we started would be able to build a cluster and sometimes not. We then found a log message that the IP Adress of the second node was added to a Hazelcast blacklist automatically. After a little while it appears to be delisted, since the connection was being established after a while in that we didn't do anything but printing the node list with the command cluster:node-list.

We'd really appreciate any help with this problem. Thanks :)

Hazelcast version: 3.8.9 (due to all newer versions not being able to solve all dependencies for OSGi)
Apache Karaf Cellar version: 4.1.1
Cluster size: 2 Nodes
Number of clients: 2
Java version: 1.8
Operating system: macOs High Sierra 10.13.5 und 10.13.6

Log:

```
09:38:37.027 WARN [pool-10-thread-1] Name of the hazelcast schema location incorrect using default
09:38:37.244 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] [LOCAL] [cellar] [3.8.5] Interfaces is disabled, trying to pick one address from TCP-IP config addresses: [172.16.45.22]
09:38:37.244 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] [LOCAL] [cellar] [3.8.5] Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
09:38:37.245 WARN [pool-10-thread-1] [LOCAL] [cellar] [3.8.5] Could not find a matching address to start with! Picking one of non-loopback addresses.
09:38:37.249 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] [LOCAL] [cellar] [3.8.5] Picked [172.16.34.155]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
09:38:37.257 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Hazelcast 3.8.5 (20170906 - e424927) starting at [172.16.34.155]:5701
09:38:37.257 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
09:38:37.257 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
09:38:37.390 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Backpressure is disabled
09:38:37.722 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Creating TcpIpJoiner
09:38:37.848 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Starting 8 partition threads
09:38:37.849 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Starting 5 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
09:38:37.855 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] [172.16.34.155]:5701 is STARTING
09:38:37.881 INFO [hz.cellar.cached.thread-3] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Connecting to /172.16.45.22:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
09:38:37.881 INFO [hz.cellar.cached.thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Connecting to /172.16.45.22:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
09:38:37.881 INFO [hz.cellar.cached.thread-2] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Connecting to /172.16.45.22:5702, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
09:38:37.904 INFO [hz.cellar.cached.thread-3] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Could not connect to: /172.16.45.22:5703. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /172.16.45.22:5703]
09:38:37.904 INFO [hz.cellar.cached.thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Could not connect to: /172.16.45.22:5701. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /172.16.45.22:5701]
09:38:37.905 INFO [hz.cellar.cached.thread-3] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] [172.16.45.22]:5703 is added to the blacklist.
09:38:37.905 INFO [hz.cellar.cached.thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] [172.16.45.22]:5701 is added to the blacklist.
09:38:37.905 INFO [hz.cellar.cached.thread-2] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Could not connect to: /172.16.45.22:5702. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /172.16.45.22:5702]
09:38:37.905 INFO [hz.cellar.cached.thread-2] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] [172.16.45.22]:5702 is added to the blacklist.
09:38:38.882 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Cluster version set to 3.8
09:38:38.883 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5]
Members [1] {
   Member [172.16.34.155]:5701 - b4ed8157-ffea-4d1f-88ad-76afbfbbff11 this
}
09:38:38.903 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] [172.16.34.155]:5701 is STARTED
09:38:38.952 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Initializing cluster partition table arrangement...
09:38:39.037 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] Registering commands for bundle org.apache.karaf.cellar.kar/4.1.1
09:38:39.038 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] Registering commands for bundle org.apache.karaf.cellar.config/4.1.1
09:38:39.039 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] Registering commands for bundle org.apache.karaf.cellar.bundle/4.1.1
09:38:39.042 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] Registering commands for bundle org.apache.karaf.cellar.features/4.1.1
09:38:39.047 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] Registering commands for bundle org.apache.karaf.cellar.core/4.1.1
09:38:39.063 INFO [pool-10-thread-1] Registering commands for bundle org.apache.karaf.cellar.shell/4.1.1
09:43:49.196 INFO [hz.cellar.cached.thread-2] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Established socket connection between /172.16.34.155:62099 and /172.16.45.22:5701
09:43:49.253 INFO [hz.cellar.cached.thread-1] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] [172.16.45.22]:5701 should merge to us , both have the same data member count: 1
09:45:42.094 INFO [hz.cellar.IO.thread-in-0] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Connection[id=1, /172.16.34.155:62099->/172.16.45.22:5701, endpoint=[172.16.45.22]:5701, alive=false, type=MEMBER] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
09:45:49.155 INFO [hz.cellar.cached.thread-7] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5] Established socket connection between /172.16.34.155:62134 and /172.16.45.22:5701
09:45:55.176 INFO [hz.cellar.priority-generic-operation.thread-0] [172.16.34.155]:5701 [cellar] [3.8.5]
```

Comment: An address is added to blacklist when connection to that address fails during cluster discovery. In your case the reasons is `SocketException[Connection refused to address /172.16.45.22:5701]`. So that means, during startup of `[172.16.34.155]:5701`, `172.16.45.22:5701` was not listening for connection requests.

Comment: At some point later, split-brain discovery process detects that these two can merge and that's why there's a connection established between two: `Established socket connection between /172.16.34.155:62099 and /172.16.45.22:570`.  Can you also share startup logs of `172.16.45.22:5701` ?

Comment: @mdogan Unfortunately I haven't saved the logs from that node. It's also not reproducible, just sometimes the connection wouldn't be established, so we thought that might correlate with that putting on the blacklist. But if it's this way around, that it is put on the blacklist after the connection was refused, we'll have another look why that occurred. Thanks :)